# Detect when Discord bot was authorized on server

Tags: python, discord

Just started to implement a simple bot for Discord.
All goes well but I just cannot find an info on how to detect when bot was authorized on some server.
I mean when somebody use OAuth2 link provided in Discord developer portal to add my bot to a server.
How can I get ID of this server? Is there some event for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the event when your bot joins a guild using the `on_guild_join()` event: (ref: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.guilds)

```
@client.event
def on_guild_join(guild):
    # Do something
```

You can always get the list of guilds your bot is in by using `client.guilds` (ref: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.guilds) Note that you require permissions to access this event.